# Specialization of template <class T> definition of template <class T>

Tags: c++

```
namespace std {

    template <> 
    class hash<nGram>{
        public :
            size_t operator()( const nGram &k ) const
            {
                return k.m_hashval;
            }
    };
};
```

I know I need to add a namespace in somewhere. BUt I don't know where or how. I am very new to this.

> Error message : specialization of 'template struct std::tr1::hash' in different namespace
>   ?/?/gcc/V4.1.2/bin/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/tr1/functional1:1101: error : from definition of 'template  struct std:tr1::hash'

Comment: one is `std::tr1`, one is `std`

Comment: Upgrade your compiler

Comment: I can't. It's the school computers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `namespace tr1` around the template declaration, but inside the std namespace.

Comment: So putting it like "namespace tr1{ " in the line after std. And make it end right before std ends?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I have been googling like 2 hours.